# сборка предустановленного приложения

Tags: android, сборка, build, apk

Существует ли разница между сборкой предустановленного приложения и сборкой стороннего приложения? Отличается .apk-файлы первой от второй? Если есть разница, то в чем она? Какие требования предъявляются?

Comment: Что есть предустановленное и что стороннее приложение?

Comment: предустановленное - приложение, устанавливаемое производителем телефона, стороннее - приложение, которое устанавливает пользователь

Comment: То есть вы хотите собрать какое-то стандартное андроид приложение (например, калькулятор) из исходников AOSP и узнать чем оно будет отличаться от оригинального, предустановленного на телефоне?

Comment: не совсем... точнее, я сам написал "калькулятор", есть сборка,могу его разместить на маркете, и его будут скачивать. А могу отправить производителю телефонов, для предустановки. Хочу узнать, могу отправить эту же сборку, или надо для производителя делать какую-то другую, отличную от моей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем уверен, что понимаю о чем идет речь, попробую ответить в меру своего понимания.

У каждого вендора (то бишь производителя) телефонов (по крайней мере у серьезных вендоров) имеется свои системные сертификаты, которым их версия оси/оболочки безусловно доверяет, соответственно приложения подписанные такими сертификатами имеют доступ к пермишенам/API недоступным простым смертным.

[Здесь обсуждается способы хакинга подписи системными ключами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature). Ни разу не уверен, что все это работает, ибо чукча не хакер, а простой девелопер.

Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу:

> Хочу узнать, могу отправить эту же сборку, или надо для производителя делать какую-то другую, отличную от моей?

Сборка наверное должна быть другая, поскольку в любом случае отличается манифест, наличием атрибута:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

Но этот атрибут не будет активирован пока не появится подпись вендора под ним. Технически APK можно подписать несколькими ключами, но проблема в том, что маркет не понимает приложения с несколькими подписями. Так что вам как то надо будет договориться с вендором, чтобы они подписали ваш калькулятор своей подписью - иначе не взлетит. Как вариант им можно послать неподписанный APK, они сами и подпишут его.